# Path Finding for mobile robot going to infinite loop

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

```
import java.util.*;
public class path1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Maze design 1 indicate a cell with obstacles
    int[][] grid = new int[][]{{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
    //Initial position of the Robot
    int[] init = new int[]{0, 0};
    //Goal position of the Robot
    int[] goal = new int[]{grid.length - 1, grid[0].length - 1};
    //The cost function which is initially defined as 1
    int cost = 1;
    //Movement of a robot(-1,0)->up,(0,-1)->left,(1,0)->down,(0,1)->right
    int[][] delta = new int[][]{{-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};
    path1 a =new path1();
    a.search(init,goal,grid,delta,cost);
}
    public static int[] search(int[]init,int [] goal,int[][] grid,int[][] delta,int cost) {
     
       int[][] closed = new int[5][6];
        closed[init[0]] [init[1]]=1;

        int x=init[0];
        int  y = init[1];
        int g=0;
        ArrayList <Integer>open= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        open.add(g);
        open.add(x);
        open.add(y);
       
        boolean found=false;
        boolean resign=false;
        while (!found && !resign) {
           if (open.size() == 0) {
                resign = true;
                System.out.println("Fail");
            } else {

               Collections.sort(open);
               Collections.reverse(open);
               Collection.pop(open);//I think error in this line as java arraylist cannot allow pop function but I have to pop the last element from the list and remove it from list. So how can I do that?
               x = open.get(1);
               y = open.get(2);
               g = open.get(0);

           }

            if(x==goal[0]&& y==goal[1]){
                found=true;
                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println(y);
                System.out.println(g);
                System.out.println("Search Successful");
            }
            else{

                for (int i=0;i<delta.length;i++){
                    int x2=x+delta[i][0];
                    int y2=y+delta[i][1];
                    if(x2>=0 && x2<grid.length && y2>=0 && y2<grid[0].length){
                         if(closed[x2][y2]==0 && grid[x2][y2]==0){
                           int g2= g+cost;
                             open.add(g2);
                             open.add(x2);
                             open.add(y2);
                             System.out.println("Now g2 is"+g2);
                             System.out.println("Now x2 is"+x2);
                             System.out.println("Now y2 is"+y2);
                            closed[x2][y2]=1;

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return goal;
    }
}
```

This is a path finding algorithm for robot movement where robot stating position is (0,0) and position is (4,5).

The cost of every single cell is 1. I create a grid here using grid matrix.where 1 is the obstacles cell. It has 7 obstacles namely(0,1),(1,2),(2,4),(3,2)(3,3),(3,4) and (4,4) position. I have a closed matrix which have same column and row as grid matrix.When the robot move and occupied a cell it mark 1 as the cell is occupied.

By calculating manually my cost is 11 in goal position(4,5) cell
But whenever I run this program it shows cost is 5 in position (4,5) which is impossible. I debug this code and see after 3 iteration it consider the blocked cell and go through this.

I think open.sort(); and open.reverse(); create a problem.

Comment: the cost can also be more than 11 if it doesn't takes optimal path?

Comment: This code isn't work. how to implement pop in arraylist

Comment: You can use ArrayList's remove function, and give it item's index position you want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive approach approach to find the cost of path to the goal can be done as follows;

```
public static int searching(int[]init, int[] goal, int[][] grid, int[][] delta, int cost) {
    int r = init[0];
    int c = init[1];

    int[][] closed = new int[5][6];
    closed[r][c] = 1;

    Stack<int[]> st = new Stack<>();
    st.add(new int[] {r, c});

    int costsum = 0;

    int[] temp = new int[] {r, c};
    while(r!=goal[0] || c!=goal[1]) {
        temp = get_next_rc(r, c, grid, delta, closed);
        if(temp != null) {
            r = temp[0];
            c = temp[1];
            costsum = costsum + cost;
            closed[r][c] = 1;
            st.add(new int[] {r, c});
        }
        else {
            // hit a blockade, backtrack steps
            boolean foundnextopen = false;
            while(foundnextopen != true && st.size() > 0) {
                temp = st.pop();
                r = temp[0];
                c = temp[1];
                costsum = costsum - cost;
                temp = get_next_rc(r, c, grid, delta, closed);
                if(temp != null) {
                    st.add(new int[] {r, c}); // add the stack entry back, as it is in path...
                    costsum = costsum + cost; // also add back the cost, as it is in path
                    foundnextopen = true;
                    r = temp[0];
                    c = temp[1];
                    costsum = costsum + cost;
                    closed[r][c] = 1;
                    st.add(new int[] {r, c});
                }
            }
            if(st.size() == 0) {
                // backtracked to initial, no path possible
                return -1;
            }
        }           
    }
    // print nodes
    System.out.println("nodes visited in reverse order:");
    while(st.size() > 0) {
        int[] rc = st.pop();
        System.out.println("visit " + String.valueOf(rc[0]) + ", "+ String.valueOf(rc[1]));
    }
    return costsum;
}

public static int[] get_next_rc(int r, int c, int[][] grid, int[][] delta, int[][] closed) {
    int nextr = r;
    int nextc = c;

    for(int i=0; i<delta.length; i++) {
        nextr = r + delta[i][0];
        nextc = c + delta[i][1];
        if(nextr >=0 && nextc >=0 && nextr < grid.length && nextc < grid[0].length) {
            // not out of bounds
            if(grid[nextr][nextc] != 1) {
                // not a obstacle
                if(closed[nextr][nextc] != 1) {
                    // not visited already
                    return new int[] {nextr, nextc};
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

To run call the function searching in the last line of main function as:

```
System.out.println(searching(init,goal,grid,delta,cost));
```

This will output the cost as 17 and its path. This is neither optimal nor very thoroughly tested. For optimal path finding you need to look into A* search or similar, that uses some sort of heuristic.

Comment: Thank You.This code is working.But my algorithm is not like that.It can change cell basic of cost.When it come to (1,1) cell it's cost is 2.So it moved to right.But cell(1,2) have a obstacle.So it move (2,1) cell and then (2,2) cell then (2,3) cell and then go to upward direction (1,3) cell like that. Can you please tell me how could I reverse the value of an Stack?Is there any build in function in Java to reverse a Stack?I searched but not find.

Comment: What do you mean by cell basic of cost? You can put the output of stack in another stack and then pop that stack.

Comment: The movement start from the initial position  (0,0) of the robot. Now it want to check all it's movement using delta matrix.from (0,0) position it cannot go left or up only go to right which is (0,1) and down which is(1,0).I add those node in my open list and marked as 1.That means it is already visited. I want to expand this node which has smallest cost value.But for(0,1) and (1,0) both have same cost so expand both of them and again search for smallest cost value. That's why I write down cell basic of cost. Now can you give a solution to sorted a stack?